# (VariantCopy) does VARIANT have default-copy function, or do i have to write copy-function & overider operator =

Tags: windows, mfc, com, variant

VARIANT copy problem, for multi-threads

does VARIANT have default-copy function, or do i have to write copy-function & overider operator =

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/variant-structure

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-tagvariant

Comment: If you want a C++-like wrapper, you can use `CComVariant`. `VARIANT` has no such features because many languages do not have things like `operator=`.

Comment: thank you.what if i have to use VARIANT ?

Comment: Why are you forced to use VARIANT instead of one of its C++-friendly wrappers?

Comment: VARIANT is from 3rdParty dll, i cannot change it.

Comment: You cannot change it, but you can wrap it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this ok?

```
class Data() 
{
protected:
  VARIANT m_var;
public:
  Data()
  {
    VariantInit(&m_var);
  }
  ~Data()
  {
    VariantClear(&m_var);
  }

  Data(const Data& other)
  {
    VariantInit(&m_var);
    VariantCopy(&m_var, &other.m_var);
  }
  Data& operator = (const Data& other)
  {
    if(this == &other)
        return *this;
    VariantInit(&m_var);
    VariantCopy(&m_var, &other.m_var);
    return *this;
  }

  Data(Data&& other)
  {
    VariantInit(&m_var);
    VariantCopy(&m_var, &other.m_var);
    VariantClear(&other.m_var);
  }
  Data& operator = (Data&& d)
  {
    if(this == &other)
        return *this;
    VariantInit(&m_var);
    VariantCopy(&m_var, &other.m_var);
    VariantClear(&other.m_var);
    return *this;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is already CComVariant and _variant_t. Why would you need it? And, your last assignment operator is 1) incorrectly implemented / buggy 2) unneeded because you already have another assignment operator.

Comment: VARIANT is from 3rdParty dll, i cannot change it.

Comment: Your `Data` class is basically a reimplementation of `CComVariant`, but with fewer features and more bugs. Why not just use `CComVariant`?

Comment: Data - this class is from 3rd DLL, i just have to pass-it-by-value, because i have to pass Data d cross threads.

Comment: Your original question is about passing a `VARIANT`, no mention of `Data`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't understand C++ copy and reference semantics.  Here is an example how you can use a _variant_t in place of a VARIANT in three different types of argument calls: copy, reference, pointer.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void DoSomething(VARIANT v)
{
    _variant_t vConv;

    VariantChangeType(&vConv, &v, 0, VT_BSTR);

    wcout <<  vConv.bstrVal << endl;
}

void DoSomethingWithRef(const VARIANT& v)
{
    _variant_t vConv;

    VariantChangeType(&vConv, &v, 0, VT_BSTR);

    wcout <<  vConv.bstrVal << endl;

}


void DoSomethingWithPtr(const VARIANT* pv)
{
    _variant_t vConv;

    VariantChangeType(&vConv, pv, 0, VT_BSTR);

    wcout <<  vConv.bstrVal << endl;

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    _variant_t v_t(123L);

    DoSomething(v_t);

    DoSomethingWithRef(v_t);

    DoSomethingWithPtr(&v_t);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Data - this class is from 3rd DLL, i just have to pass-it-by-value, because i have to pass Data d cross threads.